# Endless RecyclerView, that repeat data when goes to the end

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to make RecyclerView based list that user can scroll infinitely.There is only couple of items on it, but whenever user scroll to the end, first items of the list appearing and so one. This feature can work in both directions of scrolling.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693593/circular-auto-scrolling-horizontalscrollview-android

Comment: That work thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome bro :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are lucky, I did it a couple of days ago.

The trick in my solution was to override the `getItemCount()` of the `adapter` so that it works with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` value.

The `getItemCount()` is used by the `recyclerview` to determinate how many items there are in the list, and if it returns always `MAX_VALUE`, the list is pretty much infinite.

This is my example:

## Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mlayout);
    RecyclerView myRv = findViewById(R.id.myRv);

    ArrayList<MyObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    objectList = retrieveObjectList();
    myRv.setLayoutManager(new SlowLayoutManager(myActivity.this));
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(objectList);
    myRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

## Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects) {
        this.myObjects = myObjects;
    }

    //used to retrieve the effective item position in list
    public int getActualItemCount() {
        if (myObjects == null) {
            myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return myObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyAdapter.MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesAdapter.MessagesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (myObjects.size() == 0) {
            holder.bind(null);
        } else {
            MyObject myObject = myObjects.get(position % myObjects.size());
            holder.bind(SMSMessage);
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myTv;

        MessagesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTv);
        }

        void bind(MyObject myObject) {
            if (myObject != null) {
                myTv.setText(myObject.getProperty());
            } else {
                myTv.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this way (obj I changed names so you can fill them with yours, since some of mine were similar to native ones).

If you have any question, ask freely

Comment: Thats worked, mr Ashish Kumar commented me with the post with the same solution, little bit hacky but work very well, thanks!

Comment: this gives `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: @DhanuK when you get it? which line? in which case?

Comment: In `return Integer.MAX_VALUE` this line

Comment: I am asynchronously loading data

Comment: @DhanuK looks like the problem is that you didn't manage correctly the "empty list" case. could you post your code on something like github and share it so I can check?

Comment: Some how Integer.MAX_VALUE does not work properly with reverseLayout and StackfromEnd True.