# How to make different views RecyclerView as endless loop?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have been searching to make the `recyclerview` Carousel so that first item populates again when the last item is visible and it keep on showing again and again. Now I know this answer is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-do-i-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693593/circular-auto-scrolling-horizontalscrollview-android) but both these answer didnt solve my problem. Although number of items increased but the fragment which are items in recyclerview do not show anything.

I am inflating `fragments` as an items for `RecyclerView` which is nested in a `ViewPager`. The accepted answers hasnt been able to solve my problem.

Code:
**RecyclerViewAdapterClass**

```
fun initialize(scrollableData: ArrayList<ScrollableData>, activity: AppCompatActivity) {
        this.scrollableData = scrollableData
        this.activity = activity
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = scrollableData.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return scrollableData[position].index
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseHolder {

        when (viewType) {
            ScrollableItems.ABC -> {
                val view = parent.inflate(R.layout.view_module_abc, false)
                return ABCViewHolder(view, abcPresenterImpl, activity)
            }

            ScrollableItems.DEF -> {
                val view = parent.inflate(R.layout.view_module_def, false)
                return DEFViewHolder(view, defControlPresenter, activity)
            }

            else -> {
                val view = parent.inflate(R.layout.view_module_ghi, false)
                return GHIViewHolder(view, GHIModulePresenter, activity)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindView()
    }
```

and **HomeActivity#setupRecyclerView(...)**

```
private fun setupRecyclerView(scrollableDataList: ArrayList<ScrollableData>) {
        linearLayoutManager = CustomLinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, !DeviceConfig.instance!!.isRegularDevice)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        recycler_view.adapter = mainScreenAdapter

        mainScreenAdapter.initialize(scrollableDataList, this)
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GravityPagerSnapHelper(if (DeviceConfig.instance!!.isRegularDevice) Gravity.START else Gravity.END, true, this).attachToRecyclerView(recycler_view)
        recyclerViewScrollListener()
    }
```

and 
**CustomLinearLayoutManager**

```
class CustomLinearLayoutManager(context: Context, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean)
    : LinearLayoutManager(context, orientation, reverseLayout) {

    var isScrollEnabled = true

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally()
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically()
    }
}
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: You can try using [this](https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager) library.

Comment: @AshuTyagi it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after extensive searching, found [this](https://github.com/tomoima525/CirculerAutoScrollingRecyclerView) solution.

So this is what I did

**RecyclerViewAdapterClass**

```
  fun initialize(scrollableData: ArrayList<ScrollableData>, activity: AppCompatActivity) {
            this.scrollableData = scrollableData
            this.activity = activity
            list = /*listOf(scrollableData.last()) +*/ scrollableData + listOf(scrollableData.first()) //this is very important
            }
    ...
      override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return list[position %  list.size].index
    }
```

**HomeActivity#setupRecyclerView(...)**

```
mainScreenAdapter.itemCount.takeIf { it > 1 }
                ?.apply {
                    onScrollListener = OnScrollListener(
                            mainScreenAdapter.itemCount,
                            linearLayoutManager
                    ) {
                       //some code here
                    }
                    recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
                    recycler_view.scrollToPosition(0)
                }
```

**OnScrollListener**

```
internal class OnScrollListener(val itemCount: Int, val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager,
                                    val stateChanged: (Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        var isLooping = false
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView!!, dx, dy)
            val firstItemVisible = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

            if (firstItemVisible > 0 && firstItemVisible % (itemCount - 1) == 0) {
                // When position reaches end of the list, it sho    uld go back to the beginning
                isLooping = true
                recyclerView?.scrollToPosition(0)
            } /*else if (firstItemVisible == 0) {
                // When position reaches beginning of the list, it should go back to the end
                recyclerView?.scrollToPosition(itemCount-1)
            }*/
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView!!, newState)
            var loop = newState
            if (isLooping) {
                loop = 100
                isLooping = false
            }
            stateChanged(loop)
        }
    }
```

Ref: https://github.com/tomoima525/CirculerAutoScrollingRecyclerView